# Download link encryption with XOR

Tags: c#, uri, xor

Can I maybe get some help with this? As I am very confused. I copy-pasted an XOR encryption class, and I XOR encrypted the download link to my Minecraft Mod Installer .exe hosted on my website. However when I wrote the following code I always got an error because the text input isn't a proper Uri. Is there a way I can make this work?
SSCCE below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startButton.Enabled = false;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
        client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(EncryptorDecryptor.EncryptDecrypt("8a33b8a537d4e17ec4ac7041df43d892821c16dc15cf84fb33a672ab76c72119126f9c4849cf55423b0112c4b4")), Path.GetTempPath() + "mcmodinstaller.exe");
    }

    void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successful!",
        "Download",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        Process.Start(Path.GetTempPath() + "mcmodinstaller.exe");
        startButton.Enabled = true;
    }
            void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        downloadBar.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
        downloadBar.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
    }
    public static class EncryptorDecryptor
    {
        public static int key = 3;

        public static string EncryptDecrypt(string textToEncrypt)
        {
            StringBuilder inSb = new StringBuilder(textToEncrypt);
            StringBuilder outSb = new StringBuilder(textToEncrypt.Length);
            char c;
            for (int i = 0; i < textToEncrypt.Length; i++)
            {
                c = inSb[i];
                c = (char)(c ^ key);
                outSb.Append(c);
            }
            return outSb.ToString();
        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, I'm very new to C# and this is my first real project.

Comment: so give an SSCCE, don't make us guess at things.

Comment: Added the url (message too short)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get `8a33b8a537d4e17ec4ac7041df43d892821c16dc15cf84fb33a672ab76c72119126f9c4849cf55423b0112c4b4` from?

Running it through the decoder with the specified key of '3' gives:

> ;0ab0gf4`b47g7g:;22g2`;e0b4b4`1225:77`67032`a

Clearly nothing like a valid URI. I've tried a couple of quick things to see if I can get something sensible out (like converting the value from hex to bytes) but nothing reasonable appears.

If you're new to C# and this is your first real project, you should break it down into much easier pieces. Make sure you can take any string, encode it with the `EncryptorDecryptor` and then decode the result to get the same value. Then, set aside the encryption and make sure you can download any normal file from your site. When you have both working (and understand how they work and more importantly, how they behave *when they fail*) combine the two.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will research this a bit further before I decide to implement it into anything. You're right about the simpler things and I decided instead of encrypting the link since I really don't know much about the code I obtained I would just obfuscate my executable